# Regular Expression help in AS3

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I have to use tinymce as a wysiwyg editor in a CMS to populate a flash app. I need to strip out the modern HTML in favor of something flash can use. Here's what I'm trying:

```
var initUnderline:RegExp = new RegExp('<span style="text-decoration: underline;">', "gi");
var endUnderline:RegExp = new RegExp("</span>", "gi");
var string:String = $.xmlData.content.landing.overview;//load the content from xml
var safeStr:String = string.replace(initUnderline, '<span style="text-decoration: underline;"><u>');
safeStr = string.replace(endUnderline, '</u></span>');
```

however, this only works for the endUnderline RegExp. The initial  is not being replaced. Ideas?

I'm not great with regExps at all!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Remember to "accept" your answer once you've found it.  This lets other contributors know your problem has been solved and rewards the person who helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your regexp stuff per se.

The bug is that you need to run the second replace on safeStr, not on string:

```
var safeStr:String = string.replace(initUnderline, '<u>');
safeStr = safeStr.replace(endUnderline, '</u>');
```

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAHHH!!!!!!!!!!! I was so sure I had my reg ex wrong. Needed another set of eyes - thanks!